# To display series of numbers using loop and quit when press keyboard key

Tags: javascript, php

I want to hits a to display series of numbers using loop (like i am using 1 to 10000) and it will stop dispalying the numbers when someone hits specific key for example: `Press A`

I have used following code but not working:

```
for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++){
    echo $i."<br/>";
}
```

and js code is:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == 13){
        setTimeout('window.stop()',6000);
    }
});
```

How can i do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your JavaScript can't stop the PHP code. PHP is executed, the response is sent to browser, browser parses the page and then your JavaScript is executed. The logic is _broken_.

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: okay. can we delay php to display after page load?

Comment: You can perform an AJAX call to a PHP page when you hit the enter key.

Comment: Those number are created in less than a second, maybe you should use `sleep()`

Comment: Javascript has a for loop why not just do it all in JS? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript can't stop the PHP code. PHP is executed, the response is sent to browser, browser parses the page and then your JavaScript is executed. You could use the `setInterval` function for setting an interval and stop it on the `keypress` event.

```
var i = 0;
var intId = setInterval(function() {
    if ( i === 10000 ) {
      stopInterval();
    }
    i++;
    // ...
}, 2);

function stopInterval() {
   clearInterval(intId);
}

window.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
   if ( event.which === 13 ) stopInterval();
});
```

[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/cfdkdtnv/2/)

Comment: @BhumiShah The `keypress` handler clears the interval.  You could also use a regular `for` loop and a flag variable.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this, just press A to stop it.

```
<html>
      <head>
            <title>Page Title</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
            <script>
                  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
                        if (e.which == 97){
                              stop();
                        }
                  });
            </script>
      </head>
      <body>

      <?php
      for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++){
                  echo $i."<br/>";
            sleep(1);

            echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

            flush();
      }
      ?>
      </body>
</html>
```